# Linguex gloss makes text tiny in tikzposter block

Tags: fontsize, linguistics, tikzposter, linguex

I normally use `linguex` for numbered examples including glosses. However, when I try to use it for a gloss within a `tikzposter` block, the text comes out very small in comparison to the rest of the text in the block. How can this be fixed?  MWE:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\block{a block}{

\ex. \a. This is a test \\ % text is normal size
Ceci est un contr\^ole \\
\bg. This is a test \\ % text goes tiny when gloss is invoked
Ceci est un contr\^ole \\

}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a bug in `cgloss4e` that arose after changes to the LaTeX kernel a couple of years ago.  You also need to use `\ag.` to introduce a glossed example, not `\a.`:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter\def\new@fontshape{}\makeatother
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\block{a block}{

\ex.\ag. This is a test \\ % text is normal size
Ceci est un contrôle \\
\bg. This is a test \\ % text goes tiny when gloss is invoked
Ceci est un contrôle \\
}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: FWIW I used `\a.` intentionally to show that in a non-glossed example, the font didn't go tiny, unlike in the glossed case `\bg.` where it did. But thanks!